# Tkinter on linux start up

Tags: python, linux

I put a python Tkinter (GUI library) program on startup (/etc/profile) for my Raspberry Pi Linux and the program just has a label. Now i restart my raspberry pi and it's on my screen without any close button.

I want to close it and see my desktop screen.  What do I do?

Comment: Are you at the command line or gui? have you tried logging in via SSH and editing /etc/profile and rebooting? Have you tried alt-f4? have you tried alt-tab to switch which window has the focus?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'm at the GUI a black screen with a label at the top of it. i tried alt-f4 and alt-tab but not working.

Comment: And what about the other things I mentioned?

Comment: Why didn't you post the content of the `/etc/profile` you created?  That is a very wrong way to start a GUI application by default, and if you read that online somewhere, ignore that source of information from now on.  **It is not a "startup" file.**  It is a configuration file for the shell.

Comment: have you tried right clicking it with the mouse?

Comment: @SteveRobillard how to loggin in via SSH without any seting on my raspberry pi ?

Comment: I have made several suggestions can you try them all then report what works or doesn't this ignoring suggestions thing is not helpful'

Comment: I think i add this : python /pi/Desktop/myscript.py

Comment: add that to what

Comment: to end of  /etc/profile

Comment: can i connect to my raspberry pi via windws powser shell ?

Comment: **DO NOT ADD STARTUP PROGRAMS TO THE END OF `/etc/profile`!!!**  That is not what it is for.  *If you are determined to do things the wrong way, please do not bother asking for help when they create problems.*

Comment: From the `bash`(1) `man`-page: "By default, bash reads these files [`/etc/profile` system-wide & `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` per user] when it is invoked as a login shell" - therefore you have messed things up for all user log-ins - you might be able to login with `ssh` if you can get bash (the normal shell) to be supplied with the `--noprofile` option but that rather depends on whether there is anything else in the file that cannot be dispensed with. We really need to see what `/etc/profile` contains but I fear it has the default settings for PATH which is needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old post, but still replying since this might come handy for someone who did the same mistake.

Steps to clean up the mess:

(1) Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 will take you to tty1 Text Terminal where you are already logged in (THANKFULLY !!!!)

(2) From here you can kill the python process after finding the PID by:
ps aux | grep python
kill -9 [PID]
And then pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1

or

(3) Simply 
sudo vim /etc/profile    #remove the offending line here, then
sudo reboot

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/profile` is **NOT** a "startup" file.  It is a *configuration* file for POSIX shells such as `bash`, the default shell used on Raspbian and GNU/Linux generally.

If you want the shell to run a command at startup for all users, the place to do that is `/etc/bashrc`.  However, this should **NOT** be a persistent process.  This defeats the whole purpose of the shell.  "But I don't care" is not a good reason to do it, and if you are determined to do things the wrong way, then there is no point in asking for advice online when things go awry.

Anyway, if you want to start a persistent program in the GUI, there are several ways to do it:

- By adding it to `$HOME/.xinitrc`.  This may replace the [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (abbreviated "DE", on Raspbian, it is [LXDE](http://lxde.org/)), meaning there will be nothing but that application.
- To instead start the application inside the DE, you would use whatever 
  "autostart" mechanism they provide.  [There is a short question in the LXDE wiki about this.](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#How_do_I_make_an_application_autostart_on_LXDE_launch.3F)  However, I believe Raspbian has messed with that slightly -- if you want to do this system wide, use `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` instead of `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`.